# Data normalization before giving to Neural Nets or Deep Learning algorithm?

Tags: neural-networks, normalization

What kind of normalization scheman is required for the best of NN algorithms? I saw some people just give the data to signum function before passing to NN and some of those process data by regular standardization. What is the best result method?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the structure of a neural network and (even more) on the properties of data. There is no best normalization algorithm because if there would be one, it would be used everywhere by default...

In theory, there is no requirement for the data to be normalized at all. This is a purely practical thing because in practice convergence could take forever if your input is spread out too much. The simplest would be to just normalize it by scaling your data to (-1,1) (or (0,1) depending on activation function), and in most cases it does work. If your algorithm converges well, then this is your answer. If not, there are too many possible problems and methods to outline here without knowing the actual data.